# api.LookupUser([u.user_id for u in userlist])

Tags: python

With Python, I have a userlist with a bunch of userids [1234,321,1203,2348,45955] and so forth.  I'm trying to pass the userids into the api.LookupUser function.

This function usually takes one user_id at a time.  For example, api.LookupUser(user_id=123)

Is there an easy way to pass each value from the userlist into the function?

Comment: Does your lookup function accept a list or a single id??

Comment: @cricket_007, I'm not too sure.  I'd like to test both ways to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
users = (api.LookupUser(user_id=x) for x in userids)
```

Or, at least in Python3,

```
users = map(api.LookupUser, userids)
```

And these return a generator, so you'll call  `next(users)` to get the next value. I believe this also delays the API call, so you aren't getting all the users at once and bogging down the API

So, looping though that generator

```
for u in users:
    print(u)
```

Comment: Yes, I think that's it.  I got this return generator - <generator object <genexpr> at 0x039EB878>
How do you call next(users)?

Comment: Right. As I said, call next on that

Comment: Literally, just that... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python

Comment: Would that mean all of this goes into a loop?

Comment: Probably, yes, but only when you actually need all of the user objects. Say you have a website or other GUI, and a table, you'd only display like 10 users at a time

Comment: I'm planning on having it loop through all of the users.  Would it be like this?
    
for x in userids:
        users = (api.LookupUser(user_id=x) for x in userids) 
        next(users)

Comment: Nope, because that is regenerating the generator within the loop and only getting the first user